# pytest 3.0.7 error when import pandas 2.20.1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pytest

Anyone have the same issue I have for running pytest with following error. The way I install the environment is
download python from https://www.python.org/downloads/ and install pkg file
create req.file and install package by pip install -r req.file

```
os: x el capitan
python:3.6.1
pytest:3.0.7
pandas:2.20.2

req.file
psutil==4.0.0
pandas==0.20.2
numpy==1.10.4
py==1.4.31
pytest==3.0.7
pytest-cov==2.2.1
pytest-mock==0.10.1

script.py
import pandas as pd


/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py:31: in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
E   ImportError: C extension: umpy.core.multiarray failed to import not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa
```

Answer (score 0):

so what i have tried is using virtual env to set up python project and reinstall all package to make sure project environment is isolated to my local. so set up virtual env and then no problem to install pandas anymore

```
$pip3 install virtualenv
$virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 <path/to/new/project/>
```